How to replace a specific word in XML file with batch file
I want to change the value 8888 of $SERVER_PORT in below XML file.
server.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8805" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="$SERVER_PORT" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
               useSendfile="false"
               compression="force" 
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json"
               connectionTimeout="20000" 
               redirectPort="8843" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the NIO implementation. The default
         SSLImplementation will depend on the presence of the APR/native
         library and the useOpenSSL attribute of the
         AprLifecycleListener.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used regardless of
         the SSLImplementation selected. JSSE style configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
    <!-- Define an SSL/TLS HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 with HTTP/2
         This connector uses the APR/native implementation which always uses
         OpenSSL for TLS.
         Either JSSE or OpenSSL style configuration may be used. OpenSSL style
         configuration is used below.
    -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <!--
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::1"
               port="8009"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Uncomment the connector for cluster configuration -->
    <!-- 
    <Connector protocol="AJP/1.3"
               address="::"
               port="8809"
               secret="secret"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->

    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <!-- Comment the below line for cluster configuration -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    
    <!-- Uncomment the below line for cluster configuration -->
    <!-- <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="node1"> -->

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

     <!-- Uncomment the contents inside the cluster setup for cluster configuration -->
        <!-- Cluster setup start -->
        <!--
            <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                     channelSendOptions="6">

              <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.BackupManager"
                       expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                       notifyListenersOnReplication="true"
                       mapSendOptions="6"/>
              
              <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                            address="228.0.0.4"
                            port="45564"
                            frequency="500"
                            dropTime="3000"/>
                <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                          address="auto"
                          port="5000"
                          selectorTimeout="100"
                          maxThreads="6"/>

                <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                  <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
                </Sender>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatchInterceptor"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>
              </Channel>

              <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                     filter=".*\.gif|.*\.js|.*\.jpeg|.*\.jpg|.*\.png|.*\.htm|.*\.html|.*\.css|.*\.txt"/>

              <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
            </Cluster>
        -->
        <!-- Cluster setup end -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>

I tried to process the XML file with the Batch file below. But after executing, my batch file word $SERVER_PORT in the XML file changed to 8800. But in the XML file all lines are uncommented as well as shown in red color.
Batch file:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=D:\test_env\script\server\conf\server.xml"
set "outputFile=server_tmp.xml"
set "oldWord=$SERVER_PORT"
set "newWord=8800"

if exist "%outputFile%" del "%outputFile%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "%inputFile%"') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    set "modifiedLine=!line:%oldWord%=%newWord%!"
    echo !modifiedLine! >> "%outputFile%"
)

move /Y "%outputFile%" "%inputFile%"
endlocal
echo Replacement done.

It would also be nice to be able to change it via batch file or a PowerShell script.

Would be easier if you would pick a scripting language that can natively read XML.  Jscript, Vbscript, powershell, etc.......

You need to have delayed expansion disabled before the set line command. Then enable delayed expansion to make the change and echo it to the new file. Then disable delayed expansion again.  There is no need to use the set modifiedLine command.  Just do the replacement inside the echo command.

In powershell you can do something like $xml.server.service.connector.port='8888' if I understand the question.

Hi @Squashman, can you please explain clearly or if you don't mind send the corrected file.

Hi @js2010, If you don't mind send full ps script.

Theo did it....

In PowerShell:
$inputFile  = 'D:\test_env\script\server\conf\server.xml'
$outputFile = 'D:\test_env\script\server\conf\server_tmp.xml'
$newPort    = '8800'

# create an xml object
$xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
# Load the xml file (this way will use the correct encoding of the file)
$xml.Load($inputFile)
$xml.Server.Service.Connector.port = $newPort
$xml.Save($outputFile)


Hi @Theo, In the powershell script you sent I said to replace "$SERVER_PORT" with 8800, but your script doesn't have that word.

No, there's no need to search for that word. What it does (and what I assumed you wanted) was to set the attribute port for the Server.Service.Connector node to a new value, regardless what that value was before. I believe your original idea was to have a placeholder text ($SERVER_PORT) in there and then do a textual; replacement on the file, but that is not the correct way of dealing with XML files

PowerShell script:
$filepath = "C:\path\to\server.xml"
(Get-Content -Path $filepath).Replace('$SERVER_PORT', '8800') | Set-Content -Path $filepath

You can also embed this in a batch file:
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "$filepath = \"C:\path\to\server.xml\"; (Get-Content -Path $filepath).Replace('$SERVER_PORT', '8800') | Set-Content -Path $filepath"


Because your input file has exclamations, you need to have delayed expansion turned off before you do any string assignments.  After that you can enable delayed expansion and then do the string replacement.  By default a FOR /F command gets rid of empty lines.  If you need to keep the empty lines there is plenty of answers on StackOverFlow on how to keep them when editing a file.
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "inputFile=server.xml"
set "outputFile=server_tmp.xml"
set "oldWord=$SERVER_PORT"
set "newWord=8800"

if exist "%outputFile%" del "%outputFile%"

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%inputFile%") do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%outputFile%" echo(!line:%oldWord%=%newWord%!
    endlocal
)
endlocal



Hi @Squashman, I tried running the batch script you sent but nothing changed in xml file.

Works perfectly fine on my computer.

Hi @Squash, I tried 3-5 times but nothing to happened in my xml file.

Look at what my code is doing and what the screenshot shows.  I explicitly left out the move command so that I could compare the files.  Also your code is using the full path to the input file.  I am just reading and writing in the same folder as the batch file.

Sorry @Squash, I just saw that there is a file called server_temp.xml and it changed correctly, but back to me the temp file should be in a file called server.xml.
